# how to disable a combo box with radiobutton (javascript)

Tags: javascript, combobox, radio-button

I have 3 radiobutton in my HTMl and 3 differents of combo box . I want Crtl enable/disable of combo box through radiobutton. For example, when I click on G1 radio button only g1 combo box is enable & others are disable. How do I this with JS !?

```
<input type="radio" name="g1" value="g1"> G1
<input type="radio" name="g2" value="g2"> G2
<input type="radio" name="g3" value="g3"> G3


<select name="g1">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>

<select name="g2">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>

<select name="g3">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in jQuery this works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.radio').click(function(){
            $('.radio').not(this).removeAttr("checked");
            var id="select_"+$(this).attr('id');
            $('select').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('select').not("#"+id).attr('disabled','true');
        });
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
<input type="radio" name="g1" value="g1" class="radio" id="g1"> G1
<input type="radio" name="g2" value="g2" class="radio" id="g2"> G2
<input type="radio" name="g3" value="g3" class="radio" id="g3"> G3


    <select name="g1" id="select_g1">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    </select>

    <select name="g2" id="select_g2">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    </select>

    <select name="g3" id="select_g3">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    </select>
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
**http://jsfiddle.net/Xbcvh/**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VeaVh/1/

There are better selectors you can write, this just an example.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add id to the dropdown field to access it using javascript.

then you can disable it using its Id,

with `onclick` event of the radio button you can run the script to enable/disable the button

`document.getElementById('your_select_id').disabled = true;`